# How to find all the incoming traffic in the linux server

Tags: linux, networking, netstat, traffic

How to find all the incoming traffic to the linux server. It should show only incoming traffics.

Comment: The whole traffic? Use Wireshark or tshark.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a tool like `tcpdump` - it will capture the traffic you tell it to.

First, check your interface name and ip address:

```
ifconfig
tcpdump -D
```

And this is how you'll see the traffic to your computer:

```
tcpdump -i <interface name> dst host <your ip address>
```

You might consider adding additional options to the above command, like `and not src host <address you want to exclude>`